# UITableView choppy up scroll W/O images

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, dynamic-sizing, uitableviewautomaticdimension

After returning from a detail controller. I call scrollToRowAtIndexPath and it works as expected returning me to the row.  If i continue to scroll down the tableview everything is fine, but scrolling up is extremely choppy no matter how slowly i scroll.  No images just text. Is there any way to improve on this? All cells are the same and use the same identifier.

Comment: Are you using UITableViewAutomaticDimension?

Comment: Can you share what you did exactly to remove the choppiness?

Comment: Ya I just set an explicit I height in heightForCellAtIndex.